# Stock availability filter not working

Tags: attributes, magento2.2, layered-navigation, filter

I have enabled the stock availability attribute in the layer navigation and it is showing the "In Stock" and "Out of Stock" option correctly but when we filter the in stock product it is not working. 
Is there any know the solution for the same??

Comment: did you execute `php bin/magento index:reindex`?

Comment: yes i  have already done all these steps, it seems issue with magento default.

Answer (score 0):

is this M2? if so did you find a solution to this?

Thanks

L